# Why does my map function return an array of ones instead of an array strings?

Tags: javascript, methods

```
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];
   const convertToBaby = animals.map((element)=>{
      let newArr = [];
       return newArr.push('baby '+element);
       }

     );
  console.log(convertToBaby);

  Output: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

The expected following output: ['baby panda','baby turtule', and so on...]

Answer (score 3):

The [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) method returns the length of the array after the new element is added to it. It doesn't return the newly modified array. Since you create a new array each time your callback is executed, the new length after pushing to it will always be `1`. Instead, to correctly map your animals, you can return the new element you wish to map the current element to that you're iterated on:

```js
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];
const convertToBaby = animals.map((element) => {
  return 'baby ' + element;
});
console.log(convertToBaby);
```

As you're only returning within the arrow function's body, you can also simplify it by removing the body and implicitly returning the newly mapped value:

```
const convertToBaby = animals.map(element => 'baby ' + element);
```

Comment: Great answer! BTW, you can shorten the `map` using the implicit return of the arrow function to `.map(element => "baby " + element);`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks :) I just added a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];
const convertToBaby = animals.map((element)=>{
   return 'baby '+element;
   }
 );
console.log(convertToBaby);
```

This should work.